# Add method to object from file (before instancing)

Tags: javascript, file, class, methods

I want to define methods for a specific class in a separate .js file. The file should then dynamically be read during runtime and the methods should be added to the class before it gets instantiated.

Example methods.js:

```
function method1() {
    console.log("first method");
}

function method2() {
    console.log("second method");
}
```

Example runtime.js:

```
class myClass { }

jsContent = fopenContent //already includes the content of methods.js from php server via fopen

//the methods should be added to myClass here (before instantiating)

newClass = new myClass();
newClass.method1();
```

The goal is to have a basic class with simple methods. When I instantiate it on different html pages I need to extend that basic class with more complex methods.

Comment: this seems really really strange what problem are you trying to solve? this smells like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You can do `myClass.prototype = {
 method1: function() {
    console.log("first method");
 },
 method2: function() {
    console.log("second method");
 }
}; ` in your js file but its really awkward thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you export a `class` and then extend it in `MyClass`?

```js
// BaseClass.js
class BaseClass {
  method1() {
    console.log("first method");
  }

  method2() {
    console.log("second method");
  }
}

// MyClass.js
/* Do your imports here */

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  method2() {
    console.log("second method overwritten");
  }

  method3() {
    console.log("third method");
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();

instance.method1(); // logs first method
instance.method2(); // second method overwritten
instance.method3(); // logs third method
```

A node version would be

```
// BaseClass.js
class BaseClass {
  method1() {
    console.log("first method");
  }

  method2() {
    console.log("second method");
  }
}

module.exports = BaseClass;

// MyClass.js
const BaseClass = require('./BaseClass.js');

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  method2() {
    console.log("second method overwritten");
  }

  method3() {
    console.log("third method");
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();

instance.method1(); // logs first method
instance.method2(); // second method overwritten
instance.method3(); // logs third method
```